# Want to give different state to each element with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react and redux and I'm trying a simple example.
If I clicked the button, then the number should increment by 1. 
But when I currently click the button you'll see all element gonna + 1 
how can i fix that?...

```
class Menu extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }
  plus = () =>{
    this.props.getplus();
  }
  render() {
    const {item, count} = this.props.item
    return (
      <div>
        {item.map(items => {
     <div>{items.example}</div> <buttom onClick={this.plus}> + </button>  
 <div>{count} 
 </div>  }               
      </div>
    ) }
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   item: state.item
 })
export default connect(mapStateToProps , { getItems, getplus }) (Menu);
```

itemAction.js

```
export const getItems = () =>{
  return {
    type: GET_ITEMS
  } }
export const getplus = () => {
  return {
    type: PLUS_ITEMS
  }  }
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  item: [
    {
     example:"example1"
    },
      {
     example:"example2"
    },
  {
     example:"example3"
    },
  ],
count:0
 }
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state
      }
   case PLUS_ITEMS:
     return {
         ...state,
       count:state.count + 1
     }
   default:
        return state;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code, replace this:

```js
 const {item, count} = this.props.item
```

with this:

```js
const {item, count} = this.props
```

And map also `count` to your props:

```js
 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   item: state.item
   count: state.count
 })
```